# Linux XCB dockapp software for stalonetray

Tags: c, linux, xcb

I'm trying to develop a small XCB software that would go in a tray application such as stalonetray.

So far I managed to display a simple window using [this tutorial](https://xcb.freedesktop.org/tutorial/fonts/), but I'm stuck trying to put the window in the tray.

I just don't get how to get it to work, either by playing with `xcb_change_property` or by adding EWMH support to the software.

Using Xlib I would probably use XWMHints in a similar fashion :

```
wm_hints.initial_state = WithdrawnState;
wm_hints.icon_window = wm_hints.window_group = dockapp;
wm_hints.flags = StateHint | IconWindowHint;
XSetWMHints(display, dockapp, &wm_hints);
```

But I just can't find my way out with XCB

As the code would be too long to be pasted, I forward the link to my git account :

[LINK TO THE SOURCES](https://bitbucket.org/accpnt/clk/src)

If anyone has a clue ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it,

In order to register a window to a system tray, one needs to send a message to the tray. I ended up with the following code :

```
 xcb_client_message_event_t tray_request;
 tray_request.response_type = XCB_CLIENT_MESSAGE;
 tray_request.format = 32;
 tray_request.sequence = 0;
 tray_request.window = selection_owner->owner;  // tray window id
 tray_request.type = atom_list[5];  // TODO : change hardcode
 tray_request.data.data32[0] = XCB_CURRENT_TIME;
 tray_request.data.data32[1] = SYSTEM_TRAY_REQUEST_DOCK;
 tray_request.data.data32[2] = w;  // window id to be docked 
 xcb_send_event(c, 0, selection_owner->owner, XCB_EVENT_MASK_NO_EVENT, (const char *)&tray_request);
```

There's more code to grab in order to retrieve the tray's window id. I suggest you have a look at my code beneath to see how it mixes up.

Cheers